# updating records with prepared statements, checking if update worked

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a query that updates a record on my database, it works fine but i wanted to know how to check if the update has happened so i can return true and display the right message?

Now i know with a SELECT query i can do:

```
if(stmt->fetch())
```

If that is true i return true and saying "records found" but i haven't got a clue how to do it for an update query?

Anyone know how to?

```
$query = "UPDATE user
            SET password = ?
            WHERE email = ?";

if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) 
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $pwd, $userEmail);
    $stmt->execute();

    //Check if update worked
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could read it back right away and check.

Comment: @rage do you know why your currently accepted answer is not correct? Do you know that you can move the green tick?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check if below works:

```
$query = "UPDATE user
        SET password = ?
        WHERE email = ?";

if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $pwd, $userEmail);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        // Worked...
    } else {
        // Didn't work...
    }
}
```

Comment: It would always work.. Because it "tried" and sucessfully ran the query ( where it might have Affected or NOT affected a row).

Comment: Why is it the accepted answer? `$stmt->execute()` will return false only if something prevented the execution of the query (i.e. internet connection problem). It has nothing to do with the row being updated or not.

Answer (score 7):

`Execute` method returns True when it finished successfully, but, if this behavior is not enough for you, you can check also for [affected rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php):

```
$query = "UPDATE user
            SET password = ?
            WHERE email = ?";

if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) 
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $pwd, $userEmail);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        //query with out errors:
        printf("rows updateds: %d\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
    } else {
        //some error:
        printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
    }
}
```

The second check you can do is to verify that exactly 1 row was updated:

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) 
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $pwd, $userEmail);
    if ($stmt->execute() and $stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
        //your update is succesfully.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few years late, but perhaps this could help someone..

As others have mentioned already you can use affected_rows to check if the UPDATE query in a PREPARED STATEMENT has indeed updated any record.  However, do note that if the submitted data is the same as the record in the database 'affected_rows' will return a zero (0).

A workaround of mine is creating a column for TIMESTAMP with ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  Then every time I run the query, I'll also pass on a NULL value to the column tracking the time - that way forcing the row to UPDATE every time the query is executed.  Then all you do is check for affected_rows.

Answer (score -1):

Would the [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) function work for you?

Comment: The basic mysql extension doesn't support prepared statements, so OP doesn't have access to the mysql_affected_rows() function.... assume you mean mysqli_affected_rows() instead