# What is wrong with my function?

Tags: php, mysql

I have reproduced this function:

```
function getTables()
  {
      global $db;

      $value = array();
      if (!($result = $db->query('SHOW TABLES'))) {
          return false;
      }
      while ($row = $db->fetchrow($result)) {
          if (empty($this->tables) or in_array($row[0], $this->tables)) {
              $value[] = $row[0];
          }
      }
      if (!sizeof($value)) {
          $db->error("No tables found in database");
          return false;
      }
      return $value;
  }
```

in this manner:

```
public function getTables() {

    $value = array();

    $tables = array();

    $sql = "SHOW TABLES";

    if($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->execute(); 
        while( $row = $stmt->fetch_row() ) {        
            if(empty($tables) or in_array($row[0], $tables)) {
                $value[0] = $row[0];
            }       
        }

        $stmt->close();

        if(!sizeof($value)) {
            echo 'The database has no tables';
        }

        return $value;

    } else {

        echo 'Couldn\t query the database';

    }

}
```

But the second method returns me `The database has no tables` which is not true because I have one table in the db.

What is it wrong with the second method ?

In case you wonder what `connect` does :

```
public $connect;
public function __construct() {
    // Define The Database Connection Or Die If Failed Connecting
    $this->connect = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die(DB_CONNECTION_ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

It make a connection with the database. And `prepare()` it's a mysqli statement. I tried with `query()` too, same result.

Comment: Do some debugging. What does your query return? Are there any rows in the result set?

Comment: What are `connect()` and `prepare()` doing?

Comment: Let me check what the query returns. But the result is just `Array`.

Comment: I see in your edit that now connect is included. Try to [check for errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927486/updating-records-with-prepared-statements-checking-if-update-worked). I delete my previuous answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code. Use `query` instead of `prepare`:

```
public function getTables()
{
    $value = array();
    $tables = array();

    $sql = "SHOW TABLES";

    if ($res = $this->connect->query($sql))
    {
        while ($row = $res->fetch_row())
        {
            if (empty($tables) or in_array($row[0], $tables))
            {
                $value[] = $row[0];
            }
        }

        if (!sizeof($value))
        {
            echo 'The database has no tables';
        }

        return $value;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Could not query the database';
    }
}
```

If you still want to use `prepare` then you will also need `$stmt->bind_result` and [`$stmt->fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) instead of `fetch_row`.

Comment: Yes, but what would be the result I'm binding ?

Comment: This is what i'm talking. Use `query` and don't worry about that. For such queries `query` is ideal and more convinient.

Comment: It works now, I get `Array ( [0] => users )`. This is what I needed, because now I will iterate through each table and get all the row names and values and output it in a sql file as you would have exported a database table from phpMyAddmin.

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece of code is broken 
`$value[] = $row[0];`
and probably you should change it to 
`$value[0] = $row[0];` or `array_push($value, $row[0])`